# Prove that this function is one-to-one

Tags: functions

I want to prove that this function is one-to-one

$ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ , 
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2x+1 & : x \ge 0\\
x & : x \lt 0
\end{array}
\right.$$
And for this function

$ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, 
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^2 & : x  \gt0\\
mx^2 & : x \le 0
\end{array}
\right.$$
I want to find the values for m that this function is one-to-one

I want the algebraic solution for both of the exercises.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Mathmo123 I've tried the first 2 cases at the first function , the case where x1 and x2 are both $ \ge 0 $ and the case where x1 and x2 are both $ \lt 0 $ and at the second function I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

For Function 1:

case 1: $f(x) > 0 \implies x \geq 0$

$f(x) = f(y) \implies2x + 1 = 2y + 1 \implies x=y$

case 2: $f(x) < 0 \implies x<0 $

$f(x) = f(y) \implies x=y$

case 3: $x\geq0$ and $y<0$

$x\geq0 \implies f(x) \geq 1$

$y<0 \implies f(y) < 0$

hence $f(x) \neq f(y)$

Hence, one-one

---

For Function 2:

case 1: $m >0 $

Then at $x = 1$ and $y = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{m}}, f(x) = f(y)$

$\implies$ not one-one

case 2: $m \leq 0$

case (a): $f(x) > 0 \implies x>0$

$f(x) = f(y) \implies x^2 = y^2 \implies x=y$ (since $x>0$ and $ y>0$)

case (b): $f(x) \leq 0 \implies x\leq 0 $

$f(x) = f(y) \implies mx^2 = my^2 \implies x=y$ (since $x \leq0$ and $ y \leq 0$)

**For $m \leq 0,\ f(x)$ is one-one**

Comment: For the function 1 , it is not necessary to make the third case, when x is greater or equal with 0 and y is lesser than 0?

Comment: yes, that is also required

Comment: So, can you solve the third case ?

Answer (score 0):

**First function**

Notice, that $f[\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}]\cap f[\mathbb{R}_{< 0}] = \emptyset$, so you need to show, that $f|_{\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}}$ and $f|_{\mathbb{R}_{< 0}}$ are one-to-one.

**Second function**

Notice, that if $m \ge 0$, than $f$ is not one-to-one. If $m=0$ this is obvious, if $m > 0$, than $f(-1) = m = f(\left|\sqrt{m}\right|)$, and because $m \ge 0$, $\left|\sqrt{m}\right|\in\mathbb{R}$. Of course, $\left|\sqrt{m}\right|\neq-1$, so $f$ is not one-to-one function.

If $m<0$, notice, that $f[\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}]\cap f[\mathbb{R}_{< 0}] = \emptyset$, because $f[\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}] = \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $f[\mathbb{R}_{< 0} = \mathbb{R}_{< 0}$. So you need to proof that both $f|_{\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}}$ and $f|_{\mathbb{R}_{< 0}}$ are one-to-one.